# Why are some settings in my .vimrc not working?

Tags: vim

This is my .vimrc (I'm using gVimPortable on Windows XP):

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

syntax enable
set background=light
colorscheme solarized

set formatoptions+=t
set tw=10

nmap <leader>s dwwP

set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction
```

For some reason, the `colorscheme` works, but others like `set formatoptions+=t` and `set tw=10` don't

The text is not being wrapped at all (it's longer than 10 characters).

What could be the problem?

Comment: While others have answered your question, I'll take this opportunity to point out that this .vimrc will break diff for Vim 7.4 or higher. You'll want to grab the new MyDiff function from the installed _vimrc from a patched Vim 7.4 when you upgrade (or do it now if you're already on 7.4).

Answer (score 4):

Settings like `'formatoptions'` are usually modified by *filetype plugins* (and you have those enabled through `vimrc_example.vim`).

You can find out where the option was last modified via

```
:verbose setlocal formatoptions?
```

If that gives you `ftplugin/foo.vim`, you have to override that via a `:setlocal` command in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/foo.vim` (or disable filetype plugins completely).

Answer (score 0):

The `:help` on `tw` says that it is set to 0 (disabled) when `compatible` is set. Is `compatible` set in a place where we can't see it (maybe after the `nocompatible` at the start in one of the sourced files)?

Answer (score 0):

You should choose what you want:

1. Let vim format your text to have shorter lines, by inserting linebreaks: it can achieved by setting textwidth (for example `set textwidth=30` in your `.vimrc`). Then you can reformat your text by marking it (visual mode) and typing `gq`.
2. Leave lines as they are, but display them wrapped: add `set wrap` to your `.vimrc`.